# How to divide bootstrap col-md div to half vertically?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make below layout using bootstrap grid. There is a container `<div class="row">` and half width two divs in that (`<div1> and <div2>`). The `<div1>`'s height would be changeable as content size. And again, the `<div2>` should have two child divs(`<div2-1>, <div2-2>`) that half height of `<div1>` each. How can I make this layout with Bootstrap grid?

[image]

I tried like that, but not working. :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="div1">
        Some content...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="div2">

        <div id="div2-1" style="height:50%;">

        </div>
        <div id="div2-2" style="height:50%;">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this...

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#div2-1,
#div2-2 {
  height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
#div1,#div2{
  height:50px;
  
  }
#div2.col-xs-6
{
  padding:0px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6" id="div1">
      Some content...
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6" id="div2">

      <div id="div2-1">

      </div>
      <div id="div2-2">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is by keeping the column height fixed.. what if height is auto?

Comment: He asked for bootstrap; you are creating an extension.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using Bootstrap 4

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 bg-primary" style="min-height: 500px;"></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row h-100 flex-column">
      <div class="col-md-6 mw-100 bg-danger"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 mw-100 bg-success"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  /* just for displaying correctly without content */
  
  [class*='col'] {
    min-height: 200px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: This guy :) So many complicated suggestions. Amit answers exactly what OP asks: how to split with bootstrap. I dont know what the rest of the lot are on about.. Kudos to Amit for taking his time to actually answer OP, instead of saying he is doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery if you want height of colunmn to be auto and also the inside divs to be half of it.

But you might want to keep the divs `overflow-y` to `auto` if one div has content more than it can hold.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var totHeight = $("#col").height();

  $("#div-1").css("height", totHeight / 2);
  $("#div-2").css("height", totHeight / 2);

})
```

```css
body * {
  color: #ccc;
}
#div-1,
#div-2 {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="col">
      <div id="div-1" style="background-color:red;">
        Content
        <br>Content
      </div>
      <div id="div-2" style="background-color:blue;">

        Content
        <br>Content
        <br>Content
        <br>Content
        <br>Content
        <br>Content
        <br>Content
        <br>Content

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6"></div>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: jQuery? Are you Serious? To do a split?

Comment: You realize that you are commenting on a post from 4 years ago? :)

Comment: I am indeed Jonas. However; it's never too late to become a better person :)

Comment: @Christian Very true. Lets say I was a beginner in coding back then :D btw its Jones :p

Answer (score 0):

hello try the below fiddle hope it helps also add the custom style if you want to

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
        <div id="navigation">
            <label>side Column</label>
        </div>           
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
        <div id="text1">
            <label>First Divider</label>
        </div>
        <div id="text2">
            <label>second Divider</label>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
</div>
```

[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r6k51fby/28/)

Comment: Adding content just increases the #text1 height. Which shouldnt be happening

Comment: I mention earlier  that Op can add custom css according his style .I made this adjust height according to content inside this .It can be kept  fixed  using custom css @jones

Answer (score 0):

//Try this one...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<div class="col-md-12 bg-warning" border="1">
 <div class="row" border="1">
     <div class="col-md-6" border="1">
        <h3>First Column</h3>
     </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" border="1">
         <div class="row bg-danger">
             <h3>Second Column First Row<h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row bg-success">
             <h3>Second Column Second Row</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="shared/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="shared/shiny.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared/shiny.css"/>
</head>
<style>

.cn {
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    height: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.video-player-container{
    height: 500px;
    background-color: gray;
}
.video-container{
    min-height: 350px;

}

    </style>
<body>

  <h1>HTML UI</h1>
<div class="col-lg-12 video-player-container">
    <div class="cn"></div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Two js includes and yet another css; just to do a split? Is that the most complicated answer you could come up with? :)

Answer (score 0):

Suprisingly super easy with [Bootstrap 5 flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/)
Probably i am missing something

```html
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 bg-primary" style="min-height: 500px;">Some main content</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="row h-100 flex-column">
      <div class="flex-fill bg-danger">Part 1</div>
      <div class="flex-fill bg-success">Part 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```